# Listbox items overflow

Tags: c#, listbox

Whenever I use a for loop so select each item in the Listbox Using Listbox.SetSelected(i) it overflows over the Listbox. anyone has a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow"?

Comment: Which listbox... winforms? Wpf? SL? webforms? cf? And what code to loop/set?

Comment: I hope you have problem in your loop, items array starts from 0.Please post the code that would be helpful

Comment: Post a screenshot, show us the `for` loop code that you're using, and indicate which technology you're using (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention `for` and *overflow*, I assume the problem is an index range; most .NET indexers are 0-based, so you need:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < collection.Length ; i++)
{
    collection[i].DoSomething();
}
```

Note also that in most cases `foreach` is simpler and safer:

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: I started from it isn't the case. I did exactly what you wrote and I used Listbox.SetSelected[i] method. and when I say overflow I mean that the index overflows over the listbox and it messes up the form. I'd very like to get an answer for this

Comment: @CoNfI "mean that the index overflows over the listbox and it messes up the form" still doesn't add anything (as Cody says - maybe add a screenshot) - and you still haven't told us what technology you are using; "c#" + "listbox" has *at least* 4 diffedrent interpretations

Comment: here's a picture - http://i53.tinypic.com/2qwn5t5.jpg. What do you mean by asking which technology I'm using? I'm just for-looping and getting all the items inside a ListBox selected. You mentioned earlier that a foreach loop would be much safer, I just can't get it done, how do I define a ListBox Item variable? btw, I didn't get the chance to THANK YOU, so, thank you mate, you're really helping me.

Comment: @CoNfi - "What do you mean by asking which technology I'm using?" There is no single, unambiguous thing called a `ListBox`. Each UI stack has a separate `ListBox` ***unrelated to the others***. Windows Forms has one. WPF has one. Silverlight has one. Web Forms has one. Windows Mobile has one. That picture could be WPF or it could be Windows Forms; which is it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, got it. It's Windows Forms.